# ASP.NET MVC Data won't be saved in SQL db

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to save my model into a SQL database, but after calling the method `CreateReservation`, the database is still without data. I get no error.

```
public async Task CreateReservation(DateTime date, int _id, string name)
{
    ReservationModel reservationModel = new ReservationModel { Cas = date, Name = name, Id = _id,Room= await _roomModel.GetRoom(_id) };

    await _db.Reservations.AddAsync(reservationModel);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Model

```
public class ReservationModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Cas { get; set; }

    public RoomModel Room { get; set; }

    public ReservationModel()
    {
    }

    public ReservationModel(int id, string name, DateTime cas, RoomModel room)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Cas = cas;
        Room = room;
    }
}
```

Method is called from a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Home/Room/Create_reservation")]
public IActionResult CreateReservation([Bind("Name")] ReservationModel reservationModel)
{
    _reservation.CreateReservation((DateTime)TempData["Date"], (int)TempData["Id"],reservationModel.Name);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: how come you don't use `await _db.SaveChangesAsync();` ?

Comment: I do i was just trying if it will not help if I will do it sync and forget to put it back.

Comment: You need to await all asynchronous calls, including CreateReservation. Awaiting it ensures that it completes - either successfully or with an exception. Without awaiting it, you can't be sure that it's finished. Don't forget to mark your action method as async and have it return Task<IActionResult> instead of IActionResult.

Comment: make it `async` all the way, or use `CreateReservation(...).GetAwaiter().GetResults();`

Comment: @iSR5 Please don't advocate using .GetAwaiter().GetResult() unless there's a real reason to do so. There is no reason to do so in this case: action methods fully support async.

Comment: @mason aye sir ;).

Comment: fikus ... did using SaveChangesAsync() work?

Comment: @topsail Nope unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in action method. I had to add async await.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReservation([Bind("Name")] ReservationModel reservationModel)
    {
        await _reservation.CreateReservation(reservationModel,(DateTime)TempData["Date"], (int)TempData["Id"]);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```